# Firebase authentication - Display user info

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use the firebase realtime database to store user information.

Here is a picture of the database:
[screenshot of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grH8s.jpg)

For example, how can I get the value "nombre_dons" according to the connected user to display it in the application ? I use android studio in java.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Hey @delphinisoardi did my answer help you solve your problem?

Comment: @PradyumanDixit Thank you very much it works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those parent strings of the user data in `Users` node in your database look like the `uid`s. If they indeed are, then all you need to do is to retrieve data from those `uid`s for the particular user.

What I am saying looks something like this in code:

```java
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

ref.child(mAuth.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String data = dataSnapshot.child("nombre_dons").getValue(String.class);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }

   });
```

One flaw I can see in your database image is that `nombre_dons` child in second user in your `Users` node has capital N, which would be a problem, because Firebase is case sensitive. I'd advise you to keep it same as others.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the keys inside 'Users' in your database are Firebase Authentication UserId(s), you can follow these steps-
1. Get UID of the current user.
2. Fetch data for the same.

Using Javascript -

```
var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
firebase.database().ref('/Users/' + uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot){
    var nombre_dons = snapshot.val().nombre_dons;
});
```

Comment: OP is asking this in context with android and java.